# Assign a number to echoed data via PHP

Tags: php, sql-server, database

This code selects the first five rows based on the criteria expressed in the select statement then it fetches the data from the columns specified by number then it echos the returned data to the page.

```
if( $connect === false )
{
  echo "Could not connect.\n";
  die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true));
}

/* Select Statement */
$select = "SELECT TOP(5)name, lv FROM Character WHERE lv > 0 AND name NOT LIKE '%@%' AND name NOT LIKE '%[GM]%'
AND name NOT LIKE '%[GA]%' AND name NOT LIKE '%[DEV]%' ORDER BY lv DESC ";

/* Execute the query. */
$query = sqlsrv_query( $connect, $select);

if ( $query )
{
} 
else 
{
  echo "Error in statement execution.\n";
  die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true));
}

/* Iterate through the result set printing a row of data upon each
iteration.*/
while( $row = sqlsrv_fetch_array( $query, SQLSRV_FETCH_NUMERIC))
{
 echo "<b>Name</b>: &nbsp;".$row[0]." <br/>";
 echo "<b>Level</b>: &nbsp;".$row[1]."<br/>";
 echo "<br/>";

}

/* Free statement and connection resources. */
sqlsrv_free_stmt( $query);
sqlsrv_close( $connect);
?>
```

What I need it to do is the echoed data, must have a number, for example: higher level will be 1st and so on. This already orders the data by level, but I can't manage to echo a number for each name. My thought was to making them to appear inside an ol and each user name will be inside a li so by default you can style list to display numbers in order. Then I can't manage to think how to do that. Could you give me some hints? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is what you're looking for. It will print a number before each name.

```
$counter = 1;
while( $row = sqlsrv_fetch_array( $query, SQLSRV_FETCH_NUMERIC))
{
 echo $counter.". <b>Name</b>: &nbsp;".$row[0]." <br/>";
 echo "<b>Level</b>: &nbsp;".$row[1]."<br/>";
 echo "<br/>";
 $counter++;
}
```